# subprocess.check_output not accepting long arguments

Tags: python, subprocess, wkhtmltopdf

If I do the following from the same machine, I get a beautiful PDF as expected:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf --title "Transaction 773 (printed version)" --margin-left 5 --margin-right 2 --encoding utf8 www.google.com - > salida.pdf
```

But if *from a common python shell* I do:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> f = open("salida.pdf", "wb")
>>> f.write(subprocess.check_output(["wkhtmltopdf", '--title "Transaction 773 (printed version)"', "--margin-left 5", "--margin-right 2", "--encoding utf8", "www.google.com", "-"]))
```

Then all I get is the common error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    542         if cmd is None:
    543             cmd = popenargs[0]
--> 544         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    545     return output
    546 

CalledProcessError: Command '['wkhtmltopdf', '--title "Transaction 773 (printed version)"', '--margin-left 5', '--margin-right 2', '--encoding utf8', 'www.google.com', '-']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Looking at the complete error message, it tells me:

> Unknown long argument --title "Transaction 773 (printed version)"

Why is not accepting the arguments?  It's worth mentioning that if I remove all arguments and just leave the input file and the "-", it works like charm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify each argument in a separate item, and long arguments are actually *2* values:

```
f.write(subprocess.check_output([
    "wkhtmltopdf", 
    '--title', "Transaction 773 (printed version)",
    "--margin-left", "5",
    "--margin-right", "2",
    "--encoding", "utf8",
    "www.google.com", "-"]))
```

Normally, the shell parses such a command line, splits it on whitespace (except where text has been enclosed in quotes), and passes that on to the new process as the `argv` value.

Now, you are creating that `argv` list yourself, and you have to do the splitting yourself. Note that the `--title` argument thus no longer needs to have the shell-level quotes either.

A short argument (`-ml5` or similar) doesn't have that whitespace, so you didn't have a problem with those.

Comment: @Mariano: You should take a look at python's [Shlex module](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html).

Comment: so fast... thanks! I wish I could mark as correct both answers

Answer (score 2):

`--title "Transaction 773 (printed version)"` is *two* arguments, not one, and must be passed that way, i.e., as two separate list items. The error is saying that there is no such command line option as `--title "Transaction 773 (printed version)"` -- it's expecting `--title` followed by the title *as a separate argument.* (Also, you won't need the quotes around the title.)

The reason for this is that the shell usually handles splitting up the command line arguments. The actual executable gets a list of the arguments that the shell parsed, and isn't expecting to have to split them up any further. You're calling the executable without a shell, so you must do what the shell would have done.

Comment: so fast... thanks! I wish I could mark as correct both answers